# Using Fourier Transform to Solve Temperature Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation

Using the Fourier transform, solve the temperature problem in the upper half-plane described by:

$$u_t=ku_{xx}, \; \; u=u(x,t), \; \; -\infty < x < \infty, \; t \; \geq 0, \; \; \text{u is bounded}$$
$$u(x,0)=e^{-2x^2}$$

I was given a hint, which was to first formulate a general theorem about the boundary value problems of the form

$$u_t=ku_{xx}, \; \; u=u(x,t), \; \; -\infty < x < \infty, \; t \; \geq 0, \; \; \text{u is bounded}$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$

It has also been given that $\mathcal{F}\left\{\exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right\}=\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{-\sigma^2\xi^2}{2}\right)$.

$\\$

My attempt at the general theorem:

So far using separation of variables I have determined that $$\hat{u}(\xi,t)=\hat{u}(\xi,0)\exp\left(-\xi^2kt\right)$$
From the Fourier transform, we have $$ \hat{u}(\xi,t)=\mathcal{F}\left\{u(x,t)\right\}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,t)\exp(i\xi x)dx$$

which tells us that

$$\hat{u}(\xi,0)=\int_{\infty}^\infty f(x)\exp(i\xi x)dx$$

I believe from the Fourier inversion theorem:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty     \hat{u}(\xi,t)\exp\left(-i\xi x   \right)d\xi$$

$$\; =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{u}(\xi,0)\exp\left(-i\xi x-\xi^2kt\right)d\xi$$

Hence

$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left( \frac{-\xi ^2}{8}\right)\exp\left(-i\xi x-\xi^2kt\right)d\xi$$

$$$$

This [https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~helena/teaching/math124b/heat.pdf](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ehelena/teaching/math124b/heat.pdf) leads me to believe I've done something wrong. Specifically the coefficient of the integral in the final expression for $u(x,t)$. Their denominator is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2kt}}$ times mine (for the general theorem case). Have I done something wrong?

Comment: The factor of $1/\sqrt{2kt}$ does not appear until one explicitly computes the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: So my solution and understanding of this problem is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by this? I assume $\mathbb{R}^+$ corresponds to the fact that we are solving it in the upper-half plane. Is this so? If that is the case, is my $u(x,t)$ for $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^+$? If it is the latter, does that make it the correct answer to the question? If it is the former, how do I obtain the actual answer? Furthermore what precisely is this "jump" from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$ you're referring to?

Comment: Ignore that comment. I misread the original spatial domain.

Comment: I have found a source http://www.brianworthmann.com/fourier-inversion-theorem.html that makes me believe the coefficient is still wrong. Here the 2pi is not in a square root. Have I applied the Fourier inversion theorem incorrectly?

Edit: Yes I did. I simply used the wrong coefficient.

Comment: Is it correct that the $\exp\left(\frac{-\xi^2}{8}\right)$ is outside the integral? It should be inside, shouldn't it?